# Can a dragon use the Armor spell?

Tags: spells, adnd-1e, armor, dragons

Picking spells for an ancient red dragon, I wonder if the Armor spell would function. It has no effect on "a person already armored" (AD&D revised 1stEd) but is a dragon considered to be armored?

Comment: Could you clarify the exact spell name and page number in the PHB? I don't recall there being, and I'm not finding, a spell called *Armor* in the PHB, and I wonder if you mean a different spell. I've put a temporary hold on while that's sorted out.

Comment: There is no Armor spell in the 1e PHB, which confused me at first. I found it in the 1e UA. It may be in a later revised 1e PHB. In any case, I feel my answer addresses the question well enough.

Comment: To clarify, I was reading from the edition revised by Chris Perkins. Editing question.

Comment: Is [this game](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/7738/chris-perkins-advanced-dungeons-dragons-3rd-editio) what you're talking about? Because that's a *really* different game than AD&D 1st edition. It's super-important to be very specific about what game a question is about, because they can have completely different rules even if the names are similar. It's not even written by anyone associated with the actual game of (A)D&D — that Chris Perkins is not the same person as the Wizards of the Coast employee named Chris Perkins.

Comment: If you can confirm that the question is asking about “Chris Perkins' AD&D 3rd Edition”, then we can do some clean up and make sure that readers and answer-writers are on the same page as you are, and then un-hold the question.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty much satisfied with the answer given by Tenryu. Feel free to edit with regards to 1e UA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

It would improve the AC of the red dragon by 1 until dispelled by magic or damage. The spell specifies:

> if it is cast upon a creature with an armor class normally better than
>   9 (due to its size, speed, skin, etc.) it will benefit the normal
>   armor class by one step

This is from the **Armor** spell first specified in AD&D 1e UA.